# Java GUI waypoint paint

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, repaint

I'm working on a project for university and I'm stuck in the last function.
I have programmed a GUI representing a 15x10 block grid.
Ground color of every square is gray. And also every square has a ID which is stored in an 2 Dim. array.  Now I am getting way points from a List
Now I want to go through the array List take the first index of it. Paint the fitting field red, WAIT got to the next index, paint this field red and the first one gray again. Until the end of the way points.

```
    public void markiereWeg(List<Wegpunkt> list) {
    boolean ende = true;
    Iterator<Wegpunkt> iter = list.iterator()

       int i = 0;
        while(i < list.size()-1) {
        Wegpunkt wpNext = list.get(i+1); 
        Wegpunkt wpAkt = list.get(i);
        Wegpunkt wpVor = list.get(i-1);
        inventar[wpAkt.getSpalte()][wpAkt.getZeile()].setAktivesFeld(true);
        i++;
```

here should be the delay..

```
        inventar[wpVor.getSpalte()][wpVor.getZeile()].setInaktiv(true);
        inventar[wpNext.getSpalte()][wpAkt.getZeile()].setAktivesFeld(true);
        }}
```

I tried with a Thread.sleep() but this only delayed the call of the function.
Maybe someone can give me a hint. That would be nice.
Thank you.

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable

Comment: It sounds like you want a delay. What is Thread.sleep doing (or not doing) that you don't need?

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html

Comment: In this way the method is painting the whole way red every field instant. Thread.sleep() is just delaying this paint of the whole way. It is not delaying the coloring of the single fields one by antoher.
I tried something with the swing timer but I call the markiereWeg method via a Button so an ActionEvent and I need another action event for the swing timer too that caused problems in the code